# Using classes breaks my code by IDs don't

Tags: javascript, html

When I use IDs in my HTML and select them in my javascript code with the getElementByID, my code works, but when I change them to classes my code does not work anymore.

I would like to use classes because I am working on a project with someone else who prefers classes.

Also, does it make a difference using classes vs IDs for javascript code?

```js
const email = document.getElementsByClassName('email');
const form = document.getElementsByClassName('form');
const emailMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('empty-email-message');
const errorEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('invalid-email-message');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if (!email.value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailMessage.innerHTML = 'where is the email';
  } else {
    emailMessage.innerHTML = '';
    // return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form" action="submit">
            <input class="email" type="email"/>
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
            <!-- dont use id -->
            <p class="empty-email-message"></p>
            <p class="invalid-email-message"></p>
          </form>
```

```js
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const emailMessage = document.getElementById('empty-email-message');
const errorEmail = document.getElementById('invalid-email-message');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if (!email.value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailMessage.innerHTML = 'where is the email';
  } else {
    emailMessage.innerHTML = '';
    // return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form" action="submit">
            <input id="email" type="email"/>
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
            <!-- dont use id -->
            <p id="empty-email-message"></p>
            <p id="invalid-email-message"></p>
          </form>
```

Comment: Because the class can be repeated you get an array.

Comment: don't use classes

Comment: validEmail() function is not defined too!

Comment: @db1975 just fixed that. It was related to another part of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, but its better to use with Ids:

```js
const email = document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0];
const form = document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0];
const emailMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('empty-email-message')[0];
const errorEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('invalid-email-message')[0];

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if (!email.value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailMessage.innerHTML = 'where is the email';
  } else {
    emailMessage.innerHTML = '';
    // return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form" action="submit">
            <input class="email" type="email"/>
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
            <!-- dont use id -->
            <p class="empty-email-message"></p>
            <p class="invalid-email-message"></p>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ID when there is only one of them and you need to refer to it directly. It wouldn't make as much sense to use classes given that the idea of classes is to have multiple but the JavaScript can only get one.

You can go for `getElementsByClassName` but like I said if you are only getting one then use IDs.

Comment: Sure thing, but just as a practice and to learn, how can I modify the code for it to work with classes?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName ` is usually the alternative. I think it returns an array. Just check the documentation